# CloudFormation default values of unrequired properties

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am preparing a `YAML` config to automate infrastructure setup together with deploying my application. The [documentation for CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-cachebehavior.html#cfn-cloudfront-distribution-cachebehavior-compress) specifies whether a property of a resource is required or not, but it does not specify what the default value will be for when you do not include the property.

Where can I find a the default properties for each resource?

Comment: I think you'd need to look at the documentation of the actual thing you're creating, rather than the cloudformation docs, to see what each of its configurable options is by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While some defaults are documented, the default value is not currently documented for every property that is not required:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-cloudformation-user-guide/issues/272

although more defaults can be found in CloudFormation resource schemas:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-type-schemas.html

Comment: The issue above was closed. I opened a new one here: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-cloudformation-user-guide/issues/1239